# Amend calculateFittingCost() method so that it multiplies the variable labour cost by the appropriate cost multiplier

Tags: java, bluej

So I am creating a program which calculates the supply and fitting cost of carpet.

I am struggling to amend the following code so that it multiplies the variable labour cost by the appropriate cost multiplier.

```
private double calculateFittingCost (int length, int width, double price)
    return (length * width) * labourCharge; 
}
```

and here is the part about the cost multiplier

```
public double costMultiplier() {
    double multiplier = 1.0;
    if (postCode != null) {
        if (postCode.toUpperCase().startsWith("WC1A") || postCode.toUpperCase().startsWith("EC1A")) {
            multiplier = 1.2;
        }
    }
    return multiplier;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your formula is:

fittingCost = l * w * unitPrice * multiplier

```
private double fittingCost(double unitAreaPrice, double length,double width, String postalCode ){
    return unitAreaPrice * length * width * computeMultiplier(postalCode);
}

private double computeMultiplier(final String postalCode){
    final double LOW = 1.0;
    final double HIGH = 1.2;
    if (postalCode.toUpperCase().startsWith("WC1A") || postalCode.toUpperCase().startsWith("EC1A")) {
        return HIGH;
    }
    return LOW;
}
```